# Unpacking list values to a text

Tags: python

I a list, that I want to unpack to a part of text. 
The goal is eventually exporting the text to a txt file and then to use VPN to implement it to our database.

The text is this:

```
'"name": "----"',

'"lei": " "',

'"parentId": "0"',

'"status": "ACTIVE"',

'"type": "1"',

'"country": "----"',

'"region": "1"',

'"address": "----"',

'"domains": "None"'
```

It started from a DataFrame that I turned into a list, so basically each value in each of the lists is correlated to the same one with the same index in the other lists.

The goal is to have 318 texts like the one I wrote that each text will have the 3 values.

The lists are - `"Name"`, `"Country"`, `"Address"`

I thought of using map with a for loop but I'm not so sure how to make that happen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "unpack" mean in this context?

Comment: Take each value from the list and put it where the "----" 
So basically I have a name list - the first value from the name list will go to the "----" after the name
the same to country and the same for address

Comment: Is this text in a string variable? Is it in a file? Something else?

Comment: just a string that I created..

Comment: Instead of converting the DataFrame to a list and converting the list to a string, and then trying to do operations on the string, wouldn't it be easier to keep it as a DataFrame? Sorry that none of these questions are directly helpful -- I'm still not completely sure what we're trying to do yet.

Comment: Im trying to understand how I should explain it. 
In the DataFrame I have 3 columns - "Name", "Country", "Address"
And each row has a name of a person, the country he lives in and the Address.
If there was a way to put this to work through the DataFrame I wouldn't mind.
Hope I explained myself better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use python's string formatting to achieve what you are trying to do, and, as you suggested, use map to perform the task on all your files.

The idea is to write a generic text, like the one you presented, replacing the "----" fields by "{0}", "{1}", "{2}" fields. Then, applying `text.format(name, country, adress)` will fill the fields, in that order, with the contents of the `name`, `country` and `adress` fields.

To map it, you will also want to unpack a tuple containing the arguments, using the splat operator (`*`) : `text.format(*tuple_of_arguments)`.

Thus, an acceptable solution is to use a code of the following form:

```
list_of_tuples = [
        ('nameA', 'countryA', 'adressA'),
        ('nameB', 'countryB', 'adressB')
    ] # fill this, and maybe use a generator instead (e.g. using zip)
for e in map(lambda x : text.format(*x), list_of_tuples):
    # do what you want of the formatted text stored in e
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

```
format_string = """
'"name": "{}"',
'"lei": " "',
'"parentId": "0"',
'"status": "ACTIVE"',
'"type": "1"',
'"country": "{}"',
'"region": "1"',
'"address": "{}"',
'"domains": "None"'
"""

for data in zip(Name, Country, Address):
    print(format_string.format(*data))
```

Is this what you wanted?